# Executing javascript returned from a database inside a JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a database table in which a field holds limited html marked-up data for a CMS.  Many of the records contain, in this field, JavaScript references.  I am trying to write a JSP which receives data from the database and displays the content of this field, including running any JavaScript within it.

The following entry in the field works fine, displaying the alert as the page loads:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">window.alert("test")</script>
```

However when the reference in the field is to a js file the code never gets executed:

```
<script src="windowAlert.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
```

The Client specifically wants this functionality (taking on board the risks).  Is there any way I can implement it?  I'm new to JSP so this may be a simple issue (and maybe even a simple "Can't be done").

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked in the console if windowAlert.js is loaded? Or isn't it requested at all?

Comment: "Field" - I believe you mean by a text field or text area. How are we expecting a javascript in it and that to be run?

Comment: user2345998, No entry for the file in the console window and breakpoints within the js file never cause execution to pause (so looks like the file never gets called).

Comment: Pavan, I meant a field in the database table.  The JSP page just takes it's entire content from the database entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it was a really stupid mistake. The file was never being called because the file path reference was local instead of absolute and the file was therefore not being found.  A simple (though belated) check through IE F12 Developer Tools/Network tab might help others in the same situation.